# How to use 'new' for jQuery.Event()

Tags: typescript

Using the existing DefinitelyTyped jquery.d.ts declarations, I am not able to do this:

```
/// <reference path="../Scripts/typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
declare var firstEvent;
var newEvent = new jQuery.Event(firstEvent);
```

But that generates a compiler error:

```
testing.ts(3,19): new expression only valid on constructors
```

And according to jquery.d.ts, this makes sense because jQuery.Event is defined as a function not a type.

I can force it with a cast to any:

```
/// <reference path="../Scripts/typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
declare var firstEvent;
var newEvent = new <any>jQuery.Event(firstEvent);
```

but the  sledgehammer just feels wrong.

Is this a limitation of TypeScript declarations or just a limitation in the definition of jquery.d.ts?

Comment: I know I can just call jQuery.Event(firstEvent) and jQuery will call the constructor for me. But I'm running this in a loop, and I would like to just call the constructor directly and save the extra instanceof and function calls inside jQuery.Event().

Comment: If anyone wants to see and use the 'corrected' code, I submitted a fix to the DefnitelyType project [pull request](https://github.com/ksummerlin/DefinitelyTyped/commit/0c7a21c753b0c851ae86748fa4b12b2416e7cfac)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a shortcoming in the jQuery definition file. You can represent a callable-or-newable thing like this (written here using explicit interfaces for clarity; you could use a type literal as well):

```
interface CallableOrNewable {
    (arg: string);
    new (arg: string);
}

interface Thing {
    Event: CallableOrNewable;
}

var x: Thing;
new x.Event(''); // OK
x.Event(''); // Also OK
```

Comment: Brilliant and concise answer! I modified jquery.d.ts to change the definition of JQueryStatic.Event and it worked perfectly.